# Export/import 50-million row database without the index?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, innodb

I have a lot of data - 50 million rows. But because of sub-optimal choices, I've chosen wrong indexes and now inserts take a lot of time (60 seconds to insert 1000 rows).

```
CREATE TABLE `slots` (
 `customerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `orderid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `queueid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `item_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable1` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable2` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable3` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable4` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable5` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable6` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable7` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `variable8` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `variable9` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`customerid`,`orderid`,`queueid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `queueid` (`queueid`),
 KEY `orderid` (`orderid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25883472 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I think it's because the PRIMARY KEY is multi-column and the table needs to be reindexed after each insert (as those `customerid` and `orderid` aren't inserted in any asccending/descending fashion but in random places). If I had a primary key on `queueid` that is autoincrement, it would speed up the inserts considerably?

Is it possible for me to export the table without the broken indexes? And then re-index it with the better key?

I've tried deleting the keys with a SQL statement but it took a long time and I interrupted it. Is there any way to see the progress? I won't wait if I don't know how long I need to - it could be days after all?

I need to re-index this table because it will have 1 billion rows eventually and the insert performance will deteriorate even more.

Or maybe it's better to discard what I've already inserted and start a new table with proper indexes? And don't bother with reusing the old data?

Comment: show your insert query. and last tried code

Comment: Right now the inserting PHP script works like this:

    Get the data.
    Create 500-1000 rows INSERT IGNORE statement ( to insert them in one "go" and not by having 500-1000 separate INSERT operations ).
    Execute the INSERT IGNORE query.

Comment: Few more things to try: (1) add your data using multiple-row inserts, (2) batch a number of inserts together (e.g. 1000) inside a transaction, (3) both of the above together. That might net you some performance improvements.

Answer (score 2):

You can export the table using disable keys option.

Refer this link 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/does-mysqldump-export-indices-by-default

Answer (score 1):

The big question is, what will this table be used for? If the only queries are going to be ranges of ORDER_IDs or aggregates on ITEM_IDs, then you just need individual indexes on those columns. Make the QUEUE_ID the primary key (since auto increment ensures the unique and not null anyway). Try the following:

Update: As per the OP's comment below, there can be multiple order ids per customer and vice versa, but the combination has to be unique. IMO, it is easier to create a satellite table with the unique constraint satisfied, and use the index from that table in this `slots` table.

```
CREATE TABLE cust_order (
    combo_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    customerid int(11) NOT NULL,
    orderid int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY combo_id,
    INDEX customerid (customerid),
    INDEX orderid (orderid),
    UNIQUE KEY combination (customerid, orderid)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `slots` (
 `combo_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `queueid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `item_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable1` int(3) NOT NULL,
 ...
 ...
 `variable9` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY `queueid`,
 INDEX `combo_id` (`combo_id`),
 INDEX `itemid` (`itemid`),
 FOREIGN KEY (combo_id)
   REFERENCES cust_order (combo_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

You have to run two different insert queries. First, you load the combo table, which takes care of just the numerical index without the satellite data and it should be really fast. Afterwards, when you insert into the `slots`, lookup via the customerid + orderid will be really fast and you just use the combo_id as the foreign key.

**Please note** that you must use the InnoDB engine for the Foreign Keys to work.

Comment: I need to ensure that customerid and orderid are both unique ( there can be multiple customers for one orderid and vice versa ) The high value for auto-increment is the relict of my few imports - I think it's where it came from.

Comment: Well, did anything work? Please mark any of the answers correct or post your own answer.

Comment: I've had to delete all the data and rebuild the structure. I will post my solution soon - once I finish setting it up. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin, first copy your table using Operations, but choose "Structure only". Then in your copied table, change the structure (remove the unwanted indexes). Then from your original table, using Operations, copy it to your copied table, with "data only".

If this last copy operation gives you troubles, export just the data from the original table (from the Custom panel and import it to your copied table.